alguien podria compartirme como solucionar este error de firebase con mi llamada a la base de datos?
cuando abro por primera vez en el dia mi pagina web, carga todo el almacenamiento de la base de datos correctamente, luego de 3 o 4 intentos empieza a devolverme este error
FirebaseDataFetcher.js:10 [2024-05-02T17:38:01.739Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (10.9.0): Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Backend didn't respond within 10 seconds.
This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend.
overrideMethod @ console.js:273
defaultLogHandler @ logger.ts:115
error @ logger.ts:210
__PRIVATE_logError @ log.ts:59
w_ @ online_state_tracker.ts:188
(anónimas) @ online_state_tracker.ts:88
(anónimas) @ async_queue.ts:193
(anónimas) @ async_queue_impl.ts:129
(anónimas) @ async_queue_impl.ts:184
Promise.then (asíncrono)
hu @ async_queue_impl.ts:184
enqueue @ async_queue_impl.ts:129
enqueueAndForget @ async_queue_impl.ts:93
handleDelayElapsed @ async_queue.ts:193
(anónimas) @ async_queue.ts:160
setTimeout (asíncrono)
start @ async_queue.ts:160
createAndSchedule @ async_queue.ts:152
enqueueAfterDelay @ async_queue_impl.ts:224
p_ @ online_state_tracker.ts:88
__PRIVATE_startWatchStream @ remote_store.ts:381
__PRIVATE_remoteStoreListen @ remote_store.ts:287
__PRIVATE_allocateTargetAndMaybeListen @ sync_engine_impl.ts:375
await in __PRIVATE_allocateTargetAndMaybeListen (asíncrono)
__PRIVATE_syncEngineListen @ sync_engine_impl.ts:310
__PRIVATE_eventManagerListen @ event_manager.ts:158
__PRIVATE_executeQueryViaSnapshotListener @ firestore_client.ts:793
(anónimas) @ firestore_client.ts:525
await in (anónimas) (asíncrono)
(anónimas) @ async_queue_impl.ts:129
(anónimas) @ async_queue_impl.ts:184
Promise.then (asíncrono)
hu @ async_queue_impl.ts:184
enqueue @ async_queue_impl.ts:129
enqueueAndForget @ async_queue_impl.ts:93
__PRIVATE_firestoreClientGetDocumentsViaSnapshotListener @ firestore_client.ts:533
getDocs @ reference_impl.ts:219
(anónimas) @ FirebaseDataFetcher.js:10
(anónimas) @ FirebaseDataFetcher.js:21
commitHookEffectListMount @ react-dom.development.js:23150
commitPassiveMountOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:24926
commitPassiveMountEffects_complete @ react-dom.development.js:24891
commitPassiveMountEffects_begin @ react-dom.development.js:24878
commitPassiveMountEffects @ react-dom.development.js:24866
flushPassiveEffectsImpl @ react-dom.development.js:27039
flushPassiveEffects @ react-dom.development.js:26984
(anónimas) @ react-dom.development.js:26769
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:266
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:239
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:533
Mostrar 43 marcos más
Mostrar menos
FirebaseDataFetcher.js:10 
        
        
       GET https://firestore.googleapis.com/google.firestore.v1.Firestore/Listen/channel?gsessionid=WmcBduj_CeFOaxfO4Rt5stjkCBDZbbs1fxjiegGJqOM&VER=8&database=projects%2Fgestion-tienda-dcd4c%2Fdatabases%2F(default)&RID=rpc&SID=JY-iWoyCpcD41JhgheH-vA&AID=0&CI=1&TYPE=xmlhttp&zx=b9z15e2wxbvv&t=2 404 (Not Found)

yo no se porque de la nada empezo a arrojarme este error, por aqui siguiente, dejo mi codigo de la descarga de datos
import { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from 'react';
import { collection, getDocs } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { db } from '../../firebase';

const FirebaseDataFetcher = ({ collectionName }) => {
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);

    const fetchData = useCallback(async () => {
            const querySnapshot = collection(db, collectionName);
            getDocs(querySnapshot)
            .then((resp) => {
                setData(
                    resp.docs.map((doc) => {
                        return { ...doc.data(), id: doc.id}
                    })
                )
            })
    }, [collectionName]);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchData();
    }, [fetchData]);

    return data;
};

export default FirebaseDataFetcher;

esta todo correcto en mi codigo... supongo porque la descarga de datos funciona de vez en cuando, pero luego de varios intentos de recargar la pagina y demas, me arroja ese error, si alguien sabe como solucionarlo y puede darme una mano, me da una ayuda grandisima
